# normal flow for one element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Is it possible to add normal flow just for one element?
Here is my trouble :

html:

```
<div class="block pink float"></div>
<div class="block blue float clear"></div>
<div class="block green float"></div>
```

css:

```
.block {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
}
.clear { clear: left; }
.float { float: left; }
.pink { background: #ee3e64; }
.blue { background: #44accf;}
.green { background: #b7d84b; height: 400px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E2uLk/

i need my green block to start float from the pink one (to be on the top of the document and on the right of pink). i can't change html structure or add any extra wrappers. Expected result you can see in Internet explorer 7 :) (in cause of some ie bugs, but i need the same in all modern browsers).
Thanks a lot.

Comment: mmmmm, why don't you wrap pink and blue into a div floating left ?

Comment: You can't do this without a) changing HTML structure b) absolute positioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a clean way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/E2uLk/5/

You float pink and blue.
You clear floats with blue.
You offset green from the width of pink and blue.

```
.pink  { background: #ee3e64; float: left; }
.blue  { background: #44accf; float: left; clear: both; }
.green { background: #b7d84b; height: 400px; margin-left: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your blocks have a fixed height of 200px, what you can do is add:

```
.green{ margin-top: -2OOpx;}
```

This will move your green block up by exactly the height of the pink block (200px).

Comment: thanks, i think about negative margins too, but expected more "proper" way :(